# How does this Java code work to convert an ip address?

Tags: java

In the example code below could someone walk through a more detailed explanation of exactly what the lines below are actually doing like you'd explain it to a beginning developer.

```
for (byte octet : octets) {
        result <<= 8;
        result |= octet & 0xff;
    }



public class Example {
public static long ipToLong(InetAddress ip) {
    byte[] octets = ip.getAddress();
    long result = 0;
    for (byte octet : octets) {
        result <<= 8;
        result |= octet & 0xff;
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
    long ipLo = ipToLong(InetAddress.getByName("192.200.0.0"));
    long ipHi = ipToLong(InetAddress.getByName("192.255.0.0"));
    long ipToTest = ipToLong(InetAddress.getByName("192.200.3.0"));

    System.out.println(ipToTest >= ipLo && ipToTest <= ipHi);
}
```

}

Comment: replace with `new BigInteger(ip.getAddress()).longValue()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `byte[] octets = ip.getAddress();` -> stores entire IP address as byte array
- `for (byte octet : octets) {}` -> splits the byte-array into octets and iterates over them
- `result <<= 8 (shorthand for  result = result<<8)` -> **Left-shift 8 bits** shifts the result in binary by 8 bits, and adds 8 trailing zeros. (Multiplies the value of result by 2^8)
- `result |= octet & 0xff; (same as result|=octet which is shorthand for result = result | or octect` -> **Bitwise ORing**, same as addition in this case, because we have 8 zeros at the end of `result`, after the previous step.

**EDIT** (thanks to @jtahlborn) -> the bitwise-anding with 0xFF is necessary to avoid sign extension when the byte is converted to an int.

**Example**

`192.200.3.0` is the IP address in question. The final value is 
This is generated in the following manner

```
192*(2^24) + 200*(2^16) + 3*(2^8) + 0*(2^0)
3221225472 + 13107200 + 768 = 3234333440
```

Now your code does the same, but using bitwise shifts
192 in binary is `11000000`. First, it is added to result = 0;
result is now `11000000`.
Then it is shifted left by 8 bits (effectively multiplying it by 2^8)
result is `11000000 00000000`

Now, binary value of 200, which is `11001000` is added, making result now `11000000 11001000` 
This process is carried on, till you have the following 32 bit number,
`11000000 11001000 00000011 00000000` which translates to the same 3234333440

Comment: the 0xFF is necessary to avoid sign extension when the byte is converted to an int.

Comment: I forgot about that! Brilliant!

Comment: @jtahlborn Nice! Didn't even think about that

Comment: thanks, nice write up will accept answer... but why does it do this? "Left-shift 8 bits shifts the result in binary by 8 bits, and adds 8 trailing zeros. (Multiplies the value of result by 2^8)", could you explain that a bit further? thanks!